# How to iterate over rows and get max values of any previous rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame({'ids':['a','b','c','d','e','f']
             ,'id_order':[1,2,3,4,5,6]
             ,'value':[1000,500,3000,2000,1000,5000]})
```

What I want is to iterate over the rows and get the maximum value of all previous rows.

For example, when I iterate to `id_order==2` I would get 1000 (from id_order 1).

When I move forward to `id_order==5` I would get 3000 (from id_order 3)

The desired outcome should be as follows:

```
pd.DataFrame({'ids':['a','b','c','d','e','f']
             ,'id_order':[1,2,3,4,5,6]
             ,'value':[1000,500,2000,3000,1000,5000]
             ,'outcome':[0,1000,1000,2000,3000,3000]})
```

This will be done on a big dataset so efficiency is also a factor.
I would greatly appreciate your help in this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can shift the `value` column and take the cumulative maximum:

```
df["outcome"] = df.value.shift(fill_value=0).cummax()
```

Since shifting nullifies the first entry we fill it with 0.

```
>>> df

  ids  id_order  value  outcome
0   a         1   1000        0
1   b         2    500     1000
2   c         3   3000     1000
3   d         4   2000     3000
4   e         5   1000     3000
5   f         6   5000     3000
```

Comment: That works great! thanks! I never knew cummax() even existed :)